# Polarization of a material

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, polarization

Can someone explain where this minus comes from? Aren't $a_R$ and $a_n$ parallel so the dot product should be 1. The radius increases outwards aswell as the surface $a_n$, right?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Does it explicitly tell you what $a_R$ and $a_n$ are?

Comment: @ThePointer, that is all the information I got

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign comes from the fact that for the inner surface the normal vector points inward, which is opposite to the direction of the radial vector.

Just to make sure we understand the overall picture for this problem: polarization is proportional to the radial vector, so it's everywhere outward. The normal vector is inward on the inner surface, and outward on the outer surface.

Comment: Okay, but how come the outer surface $\rho_{ps,b}$ doesn't have a minus? If the normal surface is pointing the same direction as the outer there should also be a minus there.

Comment: Take a look at the formulas in the images you posted. They imply that if the normal vector is in the same direction as the radial vector then the sign is positive, if they are in opposite directions then the sign is negative. Therefore for the outer surface the sign is positive, and for the inner surface it's negative.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. I dont understand why polarization has opposite direction there.

Comment: Polarization is proportional to the radial vector, so it's everywhere outward. The normal vector is inward on the inner surface, and outward on the outer surface.